# Node.js - error on login form UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I created a user registration form, in node I check to see if user and mail have already been used and give an error.
someone can help me or send me an example?

Thank you

```
  if (req.body.email_reg && req.body.name_reg && req.body.user_reg && req.body.password_reg && req.body.password_conf_reg) {
const { user_reg, name_reg, email_reg, password_reg, password_conf_reg } = req.body;
await User.findOne({ user: user_reg }).then((user) => {
  if (user) {
    req.session.error = "Username gia in uso, verificare!";
    return res.redirect("/");
  }
})
await User.findOne({ email: email_reg }).then((mail) => {
  if (mail) {
    req.session.error = "Email gia in uso, verificare!";
    return res.redirect("/");
  }
});
const hasdPsw = await bcrypt.hashSync(password_reg, 12);
user = new User({
  user: user_reg,
  name: name_reg,
  email: email_reg,
  password: hasdPsw,
  permission:'user'
});

await user.save(function (err) {
  if (err) {
    var error = new Error('Problema nel salvataggio dell utente, verificare');
    error.status = 400;
    return next(error);
  }
});
req.session.isAuth = true;
req.session.user = user.user;
res.redirect("/home");
```

}

I always have this error

```
    (node:18740) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:561:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\Luca Serafini\Desktop\SENSUS\SOFTWARE\SENSUS\Sensus_NodeJs_V3\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.location (C:\Users\Luca Serafini\Desktop\SENSUS\SOFTWARE\SENSUS\Sensus_NodeJs_V3\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:888:15)
    at ServerResponse.redirect (C:\Users\Luca Serafini\Desktop\SENSUS\SOFTWARE\SENSUS\Sensus_NodeJs_V3\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:926:18)
    at C:\Users\Luca Serafini\Desktop\SENSUS\SOFTWARE\SENSUS\Sensus_NodeJs_V3\routes\login.js:28:20
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async C:\Users\Luca Serafini\Desktop\SENSUS\SOFTWARE\SENSUS\Sensus_NodeJs_V3\routes\login.js:25:5
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:18740) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:18740) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that all of your methods are being run. The code continues to execute even after a response has been sent, and if you try to send a response later in the code, it will throw this error.

This is because you are not using `await` properly. You should not be using `.then` with `await`. If you use `.then()`, when you return it will only return inside the callback function, but not in the outside function, so the code later will still execute. Try using something like this:

```
if (req.body.email_reg && req.body.name_reg && req.body.user_reg && req.body.password_reg && req.body.password_conf_reg) {
  const {
    user_reg,
    name_reg,
    email_reg,
    password_reg,
    password_conf_reg
  } = req.body;
  
  const userReg = await User.findOne({
    user: user_reg
  });
  
  if (userReg) {
    req.session.error = "Username gia in uso, verificare!";
    return res.redirect("/");
  }
  
  const emailReg = await User.findOne({
    email: email_reg
  });
  
  if (emailReg) {
      req.session.error = "Email gia in uso, verificare!";
      return res.redirect("/");
  }
  
  const hasdPsw = await bcrypt.hashSync(password_reg, 12);
  const user = new User({
    user: user_reg,
    name: name_reg,
    email: email_reg,
    password: hasdPsw,
    permission: 'user'
  });
  
  try {
    await user.save();
  } catch (err){
    if (err) {
      var error = new Error('Problema nel salvataggio dell utente, verificare');
      error.status = 400;
      return next(error);
    }
  }

  req.session.isAuth = true;
  req.session.user = user.user;
  res.redirect("/home");
```